# How to get search result in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a trouble with getting results from database when i pass query. My problem is when user type some value on `input` it pass a value to an action. But my function not working. And through below error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in D:\e.batgerel\development\projects\travelagency\includes\functions.php on line 409
```

Here is my code example:

```
<form action="search.php?search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Хайлт хийх" aria-label="search_input"/ >
    <button type="submit">
       <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

And my `search.php`:

```
<?php require_once 'includes/config.php';

    if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
      $search = $_GET['search'];
      search($search);
    } else {
      header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
<?php include 'layouts/header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'layouts/footer.php'; ?>
```

And function:

```
function search($search) {
    global $conn;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM travels WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR description LIKE '%$search%'";

    $result = $conn -> query($sql);
    $list = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $list[] = $row;
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Any solution ? What did i do wrong ? thank you.

Comment: What is the content of `$_GET['search']`?

Comment: just some texts

Comment: Your query failed to execute, double check it

Comment: Just a note, this code appears to be very vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (try putting a ' in your `$search` string). You may want to consider using [parametrized queries](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

mysqli::query returns FALSE on failure:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues

So, you need to make sure result is not FALSE first:

```
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    // here result processing
} else {
    // here error handling
}
```

Comment: i put `var_dump($result);` it gives me `bool(false)`. What it means ?

Comment: it means, your query failed to execute, double check it for syntax issues, or check is $conn is not null.

Comment: @KhShuren-Erdene *"What it means?"* you should check the [manual of `query` function - return section](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues) to know what does it mean. The manual says "Returns FALSE on failure" . You will also see in the manual examples of how to deal with these errors

Comment: In this case will helpfull to use mysql_error http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM travels WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR description LIKE '%$search%'";
```

with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM travels WHERE title LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR description LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
```

Comment: You could at least explain why string interpolation failed; also the provided solution has a syntax error. Also, as mentioned on the question comments: a query like that is prone to sql injections.

Comment: Before analysing all this, I believe he should confirm first if it works for him. After that, we can talk about optimising the query itself. Tip from me: you should never use % wildcard at the beginning of a LIKE condition because it will generate a full table scan, killing the performance.